# mongoDB php doesn't find database but is successfully connected to the server

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

when I connect to my mongoDB database with PHP, the variable sometimes contains an empty array but when pinging it, the array contains data. The empty arraay appears when I just restarted the apache2 webserver. I guess there are some other ways to cause it but I can't find a way on how to do that.

This is not my only issue. When I select a database, the variable contains NULL so I can't select a collection. It's also very hard to find an up to date documantation because [these](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.8/) [two](https://www.php.net/manual/de/book.mongo.php) are outdated.
Now to all my code:

```
$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://root:pwd@localhost:27017");
var_dump($mongo);
```

sometimes returns:

```
object(MongoDB\Driver\Manager)#1 (2) { ["uri"]=> string(47) "mongodb://root:pwd@localhost:27017" ["cluster"]=> array(0) { } }
```

Sending a ping to the database before printing the database:

```
$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://root:pwd@localhost:27017");
$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(['ping' => 1]);
$mongo->executeCommand('db', $command);
var_dump($mongo);
```

returns:

```
 object(MongoDB\Driver\Manager)#1 (2) { ["uri"]=> string(47) "mongodb://root:pwd@localhost:27017" ["cluster"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(10) { ["host"]=> string(9) "localhost" ["port"]=> int(27017) ["type"]=> int(1) ["is_primary"]=> bool(false) ["is_secondary"]=> bool(false) ["is_arbiter"]=> bool(false) ["is_hidden"]=> bool(false) ["is_passive"]=> bool(false) ["last_is_master"]=> array(10) { ["ismaster"]=> bool(true) ["maxBsonObjectSize"]=> int(16777216) ["maxMessageSizeBytes"]=> int(48000000) ["maxWriteBatchSize"]=> int(100000) ["localTime"]=> object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)#2 (1) { ["milliseconds"]=> string(13) "1618843900377" } ["logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes"]=> int(30) ["minWireVersion"]=> int(0) ["maxWireVersion"]=> int(6) ["readOnly"]=> bool(false) ["ok"]=> float(1) } ["round_trip_time"]=> int(0) } } }
```

Now my not found database:

```
$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://root:pwd@localhost:27017");
//Ping the database
$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(['ping' => 1]);
$mongo->executeCommand('db', $command);
//select the hltv database
$db = $mongo->hltv;
var_dump($db);
```

returns:

```
NULL
```

The error log shows:

```
PHP Warning:  Undefined property: MongoDB\\Driver\\Manager::$hltv in /var/www/hltv/index.php on line 6
```

When trying to list all Databases:

```
$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://root:pwd@localhost:27017");
//Ping the database
$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(['ping' => 1]);
$mongo->executeCommand('db', $command);
//list databases
var_dump($mongo->listDatabases());
```

returns a blank screen and shows following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\\Driver\\Manager::listDatabases() in /var/www/hltv/index.php:6\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/hltv/index.php on line 6
```

At this point it's pointless to selecta collection.
I made sure that the user root has ReadWrite access and accessing the database with MongoDb Compass is working fine and shows all datbases/collections and lets me read/write data.

My Setup:

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

MongoDB Version: 3.6.3

PHP version: 8.0.3

MongoDB PHP Driver Version: 1.9.1

Apache2 is used to run the PHP code.

Comment: maybe try listing the databases and seeing if any show up?:

( https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.5/reference/method/MongoDBClient-listDatabases/ )

Also, I think the "pinging" differences might not be an issue as maybe the connection is simply initialized lazily.

Comment: list Databases returns undefinded method I updateded the question to include more details.

Answer (score 0):

Now I found out that there is a Driver and a Library so after installing the Library everything seems to work now. I didn't know that the application was split into 2 parts.